# Privacy Policy for app

Tags: android, facebook, privacy-policy

I have an android app almost done and was wondering about some of these things:
1.First of, i have never had much interaction with lawyers and law, so what kind of lawyer do i need to talk to about privacy policy for an app?
2.I need a privacy policy URL to submit a facebook app review, but i also need one for the google play store, the same privacy policy will apply to both of these right?
3.My app takes data about events from clubs and restaurants and puts them on a map, is this considered COLLECTING user data ? (i am also using the user location), i am asking this because from what I've gathered every privacy policy is different and this really factors in this.
4.Are those websites like termsfeed that generate a privacy policy ok ? Or should i look in to something more professional ?
Sorry if this is not the right place to post this, hope some app developers have gone through this and can help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about privacy policies and legal issues instead of directly about programming and coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting downvoted because this question belongs into the LAW section of the StackExchenge network. Let me give you some pointers:

> 1.First of, i have never had much interaction with
>   lawyers and law, so what kind of lawyer do i need to talk to about
>   privacy policy for an app?

Media lawyers, startup lawyers, contract, e-commerce law; that's a rough overview, depending on the focus of your app, you might need specialisation in other, additional areas.

> 2.I need a privacy policy URL to submit a
>   facebook app review, but i also need one for the google play store,
>   the same privacy policy will apply to both of these right?

You can definitely make it so.

> 3.My app
>   takes data about events from clubs and restaurants and puts them on a
>   map, is this considered COLLECTING user data ?

The event data itself is unlikely to be relevant,

> (i am also using the
>   user location),

I don't know how this is related, but geolocation is definitely relevant and under Android falls under dangerous permissions (and therefore requires a privacy policy)

> i am asking this because from what I've gathered every
>   privacy policy is different and this really factors in this.

Correct.

> 4.Are
>   those websites like termsfeed that generate a privacy policy ok ? Or
>   should i look in to something more professional ?

Let me give you some pointers. Try to find an address of a provider/company easily, found it already? I didn't think so. I think you might be able to conclude from this alone.

> Sorry if this is not
>   the right place to post this, hope some app developers have gone
>   through this and can help. Thanks!

Correct, Law and other subcommunities are the place to go as there is no programming question hidden here.

p.s. if you follow my profile, you'll find what you're looking for.